# Comparing JTextField to a string

Tags: java, user-interface, jbutton, jtextfield

I'm working on a program that uses GUIs, and I'm pretty new to it. I am not sure why it is not letting me into my if statement or how to fix it.

```
    private JTextField player1Name; //It is assigned in a different place

    public void buttonClick(int button, JTextField cP) {
    int checkerPlaceRow;
    curPlay = cP;
    if (curPlay.getText().equals(player1Name)) {
        checkerPlaceRow = dropCheckerOne(button);
    }
```

There is some other stuff in this method, but this specific if statement is what I am having trouble with.

Comment: `if (curPlay.getText().equals(player1Name.getText())) {`...